# Bad Request - Invalid Hostname in IIS8

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-8

[image]

[image]
[image]

I am working on an asp.net core application, but my project stops running from debug mode(using f5). I need to host it on local IIS to debug the code. When running it locally I am getting this error "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname".

Comment: I would suspect something in the code is doing a check on the hostname. Multi-tenant web apps can do this (to establish which tenant): is anything like that being done?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below steps to solve this problem:

1. Exit the IIS Express instant currently running.
2. Open IIS Express’s applicationhost.config located at the following path C:\Users\\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
3. Find the entry for a particular site (e.g “Test” running in port 6306) which you are developing.e.g:

   ```
   <site name="test" id="1">
   <application path="/" applicationPool="gratedAppPool">
       <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="" />
   </application>
   <bindings>
       <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:6306:localhost" />
   </bindings>
   </site>
   ```
4. Replace the following bindingInformation="*:6306:localhost" with bindingInformation="*:6306:*"
5. Save the file.
6. Start a command prompt in administrator mode and run the following command.
   netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:6306/ user=Everyone
7. Now debug the site again and you should be able to access the url using host name.